# Determining the last radio button checked

Tags: javascript, html

Assume a group of 4 radio boxes with the first one checked.  Then the user clicks on the 3rd radio box.  Is there a way to know that the 1st radio was the last one checked?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez : Seriously offtopic, but fix your grammar. *Are,*you

Comment: You need to remember it possibly in a hidden and use it in your events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , there is a way to do it .  I have added your code and the completed script to get the last select radio button .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test webservices</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[name="rad"]').click(function (e) {
                if($(this).siblings('input[name="rad"]').hasClass('lastSelected'))
                {
                    var lastSelectedButton = $('.lastSelected').val();
                    $(this).siblings('input[name="rad"]').removeClass('lastSelected');
                    $(this).addClass('lastSelected');
                }
                else
                    $(this).addClass('lastSelected');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='xyz.php' method='get'>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1"> option 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2"> option 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="3"> option 3<br>
        <input type='submit' value='Go' id='submit' >
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the perfect answer to your question . You can try implementing it with just copy paste of this script .

Comment: it looks more than your short code . because i have given the full html page code still the jquery  is small and efficient .

Answer (score 2):

If you bind to the `mousedown` event instead of `click`, the checked radio won't have changed yet when the event listener runs:

```
<fieldset id="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1"> option 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2"> option 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="3"> option 3<br>
</fieldset>
```

```
var radios = document.getElementById('radios');
radios.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var clicked = e.target;
    var current = document.querySelector('input[name=rad]:checked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ej6WD/

<sub>Note: this solution is IE8+, see http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector</sub>

Answer (score 2):

1) Declare a global variable

```
var currentlySelected = null;
```

2) Attach an handler to the click event of all radio buttons.

```
function radioButtonOnClickEvent() {
    if (currentlySelected === null) { 
        // nothing has been selected yet
        currentlySelected = radioBoxThatWasJustClicked;
    } else if (currentlySelected === theThirdRadioButton) {
         //your logic here
         currentlySelected = radioBoxThatWasJustClicked;
    }
}
```